# Argument passing in vbs

Tags: vbscript, exe, argument-passing

I have an executable (wget.exe) that I wish to run invisibly through a simple vbs file - I have little experience with vbs. wget.exe receives a single parameter, the url of an online file which it will then download into a text file in the current directory, protocol and all.

My issue lies in passing the paramaters through the invisibility script. The following script works flawlessly:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run """path\to\wget.exe"" http://www.url.com/helloworld", 0 , false
```

However, this uses a string literal for the url parameter. When I try to change the vbs to accept a parameter of its own to pass to the executable, it fails when run. The altered script is as follows:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run """C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\game\wget.exe""WScript.Arguments.Item(0)", 0 , false
```

I've fiddled and played for hours on end, but to no avail. It's probably something extremely simple I'm missing, so I ask for a fresh set of eyes to tell me what is going wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no space between program name and url. The item is within the quotes so you are passing WScript.Arguments.Item(0) as the actual URL (there is no item(0) top level domain).

Comment: The space issue may be valid, but it won't be the only issue, as it is still does not run when the space is added.

It needs to be within one set of quotes, I believe, or it will not be included in the list of arguments associated with the program for the "run" method.

All examples I have looked at of accessing arguments included item(0).

Comment: It is a programming command, it can't be in quotes or it treated as text.

Comment: Thankyou, that makes sense. You would suggest I concatenate the argument to the string literal then, with the appropriate space, I take it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no space between program name and url. The item is within the quotes so you are passing WScript.Arguments.Item(0) as the actual URL (there is no item(0) top level domain).

The URL has to be 100% correct. Unlike a browser there is no code to fix urls.

The purpose of my program is to get error details.

How I get a correct URL is to type my url in a browser, navigate, and the correct URL is often in the address bar. The other way is to use Properties of a link etc to get the URL.

Also Microsoft.XMLHTTP maps to Microsoft.XMLHTTP.1.0. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP maps to Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0. Try a later one

Try this way using xmlhttp. Edit the url's etc. If it seems to work comment out the if / end if to dump info even if seeming to work. It's vbscript but vbscript works in vb6.

```
 On Error Resume Next
 Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET", "http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/default.aspx", False
 'This is IE 8 headers
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
    line =""
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error getting file" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "==================" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf &  File.getAllResponseHeaders
    wscript.echo Line
    Err.clear
    wscript.quit
 End If

On Error Goto 0

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "c:\users\test.txt", 2
```

Also see if these other objects work.

```
C:\Users>reg query hkcr /f xmlhttp

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP.1.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0
End of search: 12 match(es) found.
```

### Also be aware there is a limit on how many times you can call any particular XMLHTTP object before a lockout occurs. If that happens, and it does when debugging code, just change to a different xmlhttp object

Comment: I know for a fact the wget.exe program runs perfectly. My ONLY issue is in the invisibility script itself, where it is refusing to recognize the argument. I will try concatenating the argument to the string and get back to you.

Update: The concatenation works, thankyou.